# Facing issue aligning two divs next to each other in HTML

Tags: html, css

I have been trying my hand at Electron and for that, I am trying to create 2 divs, next to each other. I have read a few solutions on here for aligning 2 divs next to each other, but nothing works for me. Here's my code so far:

**Code**

```css
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}

.wrapper{
    height: 90%;
}

.request-pane {
    float:left; /* add this */
    margin-left: 10%;   
    height: 90%;
    width: 45%;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.response-pane {
    float:right; /* add this */
    margin-left: 55%;
    height: 90%;
    width: 45%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="request-pane"></div>
    <div class="response-pane"></div>
</div>
```

Can anyone point me out what I'm doing wrong here? I am very new to HTML, so I don't know if the solution is too obvious or not

Comment: Remove the float an margins and add `.wrapper { display: flex; }`.

Comment: Thanks so much @connexo! That solved the issue for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it by two ways.

1. remove float atrribute and add

   .wrapper{
    height: 90%;
    display: flex;
   }
2. try using display:inline-block in css for both request-pane and response-pane

Comment: Thanks! I went with #1, which reduced a lot of unnecessary code from my CSS

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep `floats` here - fixed with code

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
}

.request-pane, .response-pane {
  box-sizing: border-box; /* count border inside of a `width` */
}

.wrapper {
  height: 90%;
}

.request-pane {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10%;
  height: 90%;
  width: 45%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.response-pane {
  float: right;
  /* margin-left: 55%; */ /* this is a root of a problems */
  height: 90%;
  width: 45%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="request-pane"></div>
    <div class="response-pane"></div>
</div>
```

But yes, you probably better to go with flexbox. A good guide to it you can find here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/.

Also, it looks like you lack a basic understanding of how HTML/CSS work, so you'd better have some basics free courses to moving forward.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yes, I do lack understanding of HTML/CSS, which is why I am trying to create small apps like this and learning from my mistakes. Thanks again for the help and the URL too :)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `margin-left` property and also add `display:inline-flex` to the css class `request-pane` and `response-pane` as shown below.

```css
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}

.wrapper{
    height: 90%;
}

.request-pane {
    float:left; /* add this */
    height: 90%;
    width: 45%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    display:inline-flex;
}

.response-pane {
    float:right; /* add this */
    height: 90%;
    width: 45%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display:inline-flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="request-pane"></div>
    <div class="response-pane"></div>
</div>
```

This works fine. Do run the code from snippet,I hope that's the result you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

If you want even more simpler way, use bootstrap. Divide your screen into two halves. In each section create div. This will full fill your requirements.w3school is best website for this.